# Stored proc. not existing error #am_generate_waitstats - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Any idea why I can't run the stored procedure?

```
USE tempdb;
GO

EXEC #am_generate_waitstats
GO
```

Error:

> Could not find stored procedure '#am_generate_waitstats'.

Context in DSMS is tempdb, where I found this stored procedure. I can also find the stored procedure in Object Explorer.

Comment: Did you create the procedure using the same `spid` / connection? *where I found this proc* - doesn't sound like it.

Comment: No, this is system SP, its not created by me. Its been used in Active monitoring in SSMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#` indicates it's a temporary object. In this case a stored procedure. Temporary objects only exist within the session they are created in. So if another user or process creates a temporary object, that object is not accessible to other processes.

It *is* however possible to share temporary objects between sessions, but in such cases, the object would be prefixed with `##`.

According to [this thread](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/strange-to-me-procedure), the procedure is generated by Activity Monitor.

Comment: Not sure why you call it hidden, that's not really a term used. Also you don't differentiate between global `##` and local `#` stored procedures

Comment: @Charlieface Fair enough. I did mean temporary. As the OP only asked about an object prefixed with #, the rest of the answer with that context is correct, though. But yes, if the object would have had a double `##`, it would be visible beyond the scope of the session it was created in. I added that to the answer for completions' sake, and adjusted the "hidden" to "temporary".